# partial form data submission with FormData api

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-data

With Ajax it is possible to send partial data for form using below as data for ajax-

```
$("#CreateForm").find("#form-section-1").find('input, textarea, select').serialize()
```

Trying same with FormData api  -

```
new FormData($('form#CreateForm')[0])
```

This does not work however -

```
var formdata = new FormData($('form#CreateForm').find("#form-section-1").find('input, textarea, select'))
```

Since below loop gives no result -

```
for (var pair of formdata.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

How can partial form data be submitted with FormData api in compact form like serialize ?

**Edit:** 
In Accepted solution, I had to further add this condition for files especially -

```
if($(this).is(':input:file')) { 
formData.append(this.name, $(this)[0].files[0]); 
} else { 
formData.append(this.name, $(this).val()); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FormData constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) accepts an optional native `<form/>` element parameter to pass all of the data in the form. Notice,

```
$('form#CreateForm') // jQuery object
$('form#CreateForm')[0] // native form element
$('form#CreateForm #form-section-1').find('input, textarea, select') // jQuery objects
$('form#CreateForm #form-section-1').find('input, textarea, select')[0] // some native non-form element
```

So you can't really use the constructor.

The FormData object does have an [.append method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to add new values into the object. You could use it to do

```
var formData = new FormData();
$('form#CreateForm #form-section-1').find('input, textarea, select').each(function () {
        if($(this).is(':input:file')) {
            formData.append(this.name, $(this)[0].files[0]);
        } else {
            formData.append(this.name, $(this).val());
        }
});
```

FYI `:input` is shorthand for `input|select|textarea|button`.

Comment: Will this work for also input field of type file ? As it seems that it is somehow not being passed entirely.

Comment: I modified a bit for files and now it works. Inside for loop -> if($(this).is(':input:file')) {          
          formData.append(this.name, $(this)[0].files[0]);
         } else {
          formData.append(this.name, $(this).val());
         }

Comment: What you did is correct. `this.files[0]` also works as `$(this)[0]` == `this`.